# Set [class] property of Grail Domain in inheritance

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-domain-class

I have different types of users.
Every users inherit from a class : AppUser.
Some users have a subclass of AppUser : AdminUser.

Is it possible for an AppUser to become an AdminUser?
And for an AdminUser to become an AppUser?

I've tried to do
`appUserInstance.class = my.package.AdminUser`
But ended up with a ReadOnlyPropertyException

I've also tried 
`appUserInstance.properties = new com.michelin.dur.AppUser(appUserInstance.properties).properties`
-> object references an unsaved transient instance

So the best I could actually do was removing / recreating the object.
However, that's still a problem, as all links pointing to my previous User instance will point to nothing.

Anyone having a good solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with HQL:

`DomainClass.executeUpdate("update DomainClass dc set dc.class = '${newDomainClass.name}' where id = ${id}")`

I'd advise against it though - HQL skips validation, so if the classes AppUser and AdminUser have different properties you might end up with invalid objects in the database when doing that.

I would try to solve this by using permissions (roles) or if that's too much, by using a property called UserType instead of inheritance.

If not, recreating the user doesn't seem bad - if the classes AdminUser and AppUser are different, the user instance should also be.

Comment: Are HQL queries rolledback too in transactionnal services?

If so, can't I just change the class using HQL and then force it to validate by saving the object? I would just have to roll it back if there is an error.